# Why django debug toolbar is hidden?

Tags: python, django, django-debug-toolbar

I install django debug toolbar and it did not appear in the browser, when I looked at the code, I saw that it was hidden. How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Does the button/tab appear on the right side of the browser window? Is there a error in the browser console?

Comment: @schillingt i have this error in concole Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

Comment: Good news, this is a known issue: Check out the docs https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#troubleshooting let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: This is a known issue, see [here](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tips.html), your HTML file must include a body tag.

Comment: @schillingt, sorry but it doesn't help, i install mailcap-fix and get this error again

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed thx for your support, file incudes a body, html, head tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you all for your help, I solved this problem like this

```
if DEBUG:
    import mimetypes
    mimetypes.add_type("application/javascript", ".js", True)
```

Comment: Where do you place this code?

Comment: in your settings.py